# Website "text" doesn't get viewed properly on Android Opera Mini browser

Tags: android, css

Hello I have a website which fully responsive. when i open it in android mobile with opera mini mobile browser "text" doesn't show properly resize as screen but other browser work well like as Firefox or google chrome. How can I solve this problem in opera mini browser ? Anyone help me?

Comment: Opera mini compress the website, is not a fully web browser like Chrome or Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for reply me. how can i properly show my text? Do you give me any idea?

Comment: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/

Comment: I am very pleased for your answer @MatjažMav. Here is some solution but not solve my problem! text does not show in proper width....... like my responsive width 320px. when i open it with opera mini browser  like 320px width  screen text show only 160px or less.